# How can I distribute the ith value in a vector along the ith row of a matrix using Numpy?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

If I have a vector `x = np.array([1,2,3])`
and a matrix `M = np.array([[3,4,5], [6,7,8], [9,10,11]])`

How can I distribute the ith value in `x` throughout the ith row in `M` so that the resulting matrix is

```
[[3,4,5],
 [12,14,16],
 [27,30,33]]
```

?

Comment: So, you want `M * x[:, None]`?

Comment: Yes, that is perfect. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you're looking for broadcasted multiplication:

```
M * x[:, None]

array([[ 3,  4,  5],
       [12, 14, 16],
       [27, 30, 33]])
```